# Copy program writing corrupted Characters

Tags: c, file, sockets, copy, local

I am writing a C program, that copies files via local (Unix) Streamsockets. While my program copies the text in the target file, after the last character, there will be corrupted data, not belonging to the original file. Snippets of the Code included. I am guessing the program writes other random memory into the file aswell. But I dont understand why

Serverside:

```
    while (1) {
        /* Receiving Path */
        /* length of peer structure */
        clientaddrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un);
        /* waiting for connection */
        printf("test-wait\n");
        if ((commsd = accept(sd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &clientaddrlen)) < 0) {
            perror("Error starting the connection");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* Receive */
        if ((nread = read(commsd, &buf, sizeof(struct buffer))) < 0) {
            perror("Error reading Data");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        strcpy(path, buf.mtext);
        /* open/create file */
        if ((fd = open(path, O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 00777)) < 0) {
            perror("Error binding Socket");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* sending answer */
        buf.mtype = 'r';
        if ((nwritten = write(commsd, &buf, sizeof(struct buffer))) < 0) {
            perror("Error writing to Socket");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        
        /* receiving and writing of data */
        /* if (< BUFLEN) was transmitted, program finishes */
        buf.mbytes = BUFLEN;
        while (buf.mbytes == BUFLEN) {
            /* read data */
            if ((nread = read(commsd, &buf, sizeof(struct buffer))) < 0) {
                perror("Error reading Data");
                exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
            }
            if (buf.mbytes != 0) {
                /* write data in file  */
                if ((nwritten = write(fd, &buf.mtext, BUFLEN)) < 0) {
                    perror("Error writing to file");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                } 
                /* send answer */
                buf.mtype = 'r';
                if ((nwritten = write(commsd, &buf, sizeof(struct buffer))) < 0) {
                    perror("Error writing to Socket");
                    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
                }
            }
        }
        if (close(fd) < 0) {
            perror("Error closing file");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
```

Clientside:

```
/* Transmitting data */
    nread = BUFLEN;
    while (nread == BUFLEN) {
        /* wiping mtext */
        if (memset(&buf.mtext, 0, sizeof(BUFLEN)) < 0) {
            perror("Error writing to file");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* read file */
        printf("test 1  %c\n", buf.mtype);
        if ((nread = read(fd, &buf.mtext, BUFLEN)) < 0) {
            perror("Error reading file Socket");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        /* send previously read data */
        buf.mbytes = nread;
        buf.mtype = 't';
        printf("test 2  %c\n", buf.mtype);
        if ((nwritten = write(sd, &buf, sizeof(struct buffer))) < 0) {
            perror("Error sending path");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
```

In the End the file looked like this:

[Snippet of the file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GGRDi.png)

Comment: `nread` tells you how much is read but you ignore it and always use `BUFLEN`. The garbage at the end is likely because you didn't write the amount read and instead wrote the full length of the buffer.

Comment: Fixed it myself:  
When you write the received data in the file, you shouldnt write lenght "BUFLEN" Data, but the specific length of the data transmitted. In this case: "buf.mbytes"

Comment: @RetiredNinja Yes, thats right! Found it aswell. Thank you for answering tho! :D